# String to Date Conversion Problem

Tags: android

I am trying to convert the following string in to date, I am able to convert the string into to date object successfully,But the Problem is in this string I want to convert the time in to am/pm i.e. 12 hr format, I tried different ways but unable to get the solution.

How to get the 12hr format time from this string ?

Here is my code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy"); //please notice the capital M
 Date date;
 try {
      date = formatter.parse("Fri Jul 01 10:00:00 CDT 2011");
      Log.e("ThankYou Block", ""+date.toString());
 } catch (ParseException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY

```
public static String StringToDate(String dateToParse) {

        Date formatter = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(dateToParse));
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
        formatter.setTime(formatter.getTime() + offset);
        String strCustomDateTime = dateFormat.format(formatter);
        return strCustomDateTime;
}
```